# How to delete a donated shortcut in Swift Siri

Tags: swift, shortcut, siri, sirikit

I have a simple To do style list app, where an added item can have an intent donated so that user can find and mark the item as "completed" without opening the app.

In the Note class I have this function to donate the intent, which works as expected

```
public func donateMarkNoteAsCompleteIntent() {    
    let intent = MarkNoteAsCompleteIntent()
    intent.content = self.content

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YYYY"
    intent.addedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: self.addedDate)
    intent.id = self.id

    let interaction = INInteraction(intent: intent, response: nil)

    interaction.groupIdentifier = self.id
    interaction.donate(completion: nil)
}
```

My only issue is, when the user uses the shortcut and triggers the app to update the Note item, I want to remove the shortcut so that the user can't trigger it again.

In my intent handle function, I end up calling this function

```
public func removeMarkNoteAsCompleteIntent() {
    INInteraction.deleteAll(completion: nil)
    let index = CSSearchableIndex()
    index.deleteAllSearchableItems(completionHandler: nil)
}
```

No matter what combination of things I do here I can't seem to remove the donated shortcut.  As soon as a user accepts marking the task as complete, I want the shortcut to no longer be visible in searches from Spotlight, etc.  Everything else in the intent handling code is working, its updating the Note item in my database perfectly.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you checked apple's doc for it? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/deleting_donated_shortcuts

Comment: Yes but there isn't much there, it simply says to use the INInteraction.delete functions to remove the interactions, which I've tried variations of including deleting specific interaction with groupIdentifier, as well as simply deleting all but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Check: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/105413

Comment: I did see that same thread, it's from months ago though.  Surely this can't just be a bug, it's a very significant error!  Are there any other ways to donate activities like this with a working way to delete once task is completed???